# $({\overline{E}})^C=\mathring{(E^C)}$

Tags: general-topology

I wanted to show that $({\overline{E}})^C=\mathring{(E^C)}$ using only definitions and well-known set operations (distributivity of intersection for example, etc) . I did it in a way that I think is very very long.
First I show three smalls properties :

- $\partial E = \partial(E^C)$ (easy)
- $(\partial E)^C = \mathring{E} \cup (\mathring{E^C})$ (easy with double inclusion)
- $\mathring {(E^C)} \subset (\mathring{E})^C$. I struggle to show this point : I have the following : Let $x \in \mathring {(E^C)}$,$ \exists \delta_x > 0 \text{ such that } B(x,\delta_x) \subset E^C$ $\implies x \notin \partial (E^C) \iff x \notin \partial E$. Then I don't know what to do.

For the final step I show the equality using only set algebraic properties.

Hence, $({\overline{E}})^C = \mathring {(E^C)}$.

Comment: So, what is your question? How to make it shorter?

Comment: What's your definition?

Comment: How to properly show the third point, essential element in the (ugly) final proof.

Comment: @KennyLau $\overline E = \mathring{E}$ (interior) $\cup \partial E$ (boundary).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative view of the interior and closure: let $\mathcal{N}_x$ be the set of neighbourhoods of $x \in X$ (if in a metric space, you an just take all balls $B(x,r), r>0$ around $x$, as these form a base, which is good enough).
Then for any $E \subseteq X$:

$$x \in \mathring{E} \iff \exists N \in \mathcal{N}_x: N \subseteq E$$

$$ x \in \overline{E} \iff \forall N \in \mathcal{N}_x: N \cap E \neq \emptyset$$

$$x \in \partial E \iff \forall N \in \mathcal{N}_x: (N \cap E \neq \emptyset) \land (N \cap E^\complement \neq \emptyset)$$

Then $x \in (\overline{E})^\complement \iff \exists N \in \mathcal{N}_x: N\cap E = \emptyset$ by simple logic

and the latter is equivalent to

$\exists N \in \mathcal{N}_x: N \subseteq E^\complement \iff x \in \mathring{(E^\complement)}$ by definition.

So your statement is then quite easy to prove.

---

In my first course in topology the above were the definitions of interior and closure etc. (it was a course in metric topology in the first year at uni, so we used the set of balls as $\mathcal{N}_x$). In the second year (general topology I) we started with the open set axioms for a topology $\mathcal{T}$ and defined

$$\mathring{E} = \bigcup\{O \in \mathcal{T}\mid O \subseteq E\}$$

(so the maximal open subset of $E$), defined closed as being the complement of an open set and then the dual definition

$$\overline{E} = \bigcap \{C\mid X\setminus C\in \mathcal{T}, E \subseteq C\}$$

(the minimal closed superset of $E$), and $\partial E = \overline{E}\setminus \mathring{E} = \overline{E} \cap \overline{E^\complement}$, where the equivalence of these expressions follows from the statement from the question.

We then proceeded to define neighbourhoods and neighbourhood systems (alternative axioms for topology) and prove the equivalence of our first and second year definitions etc. All quite helpful IMO. It really helped us to solidify the concepts.